# Disable overwrite on multiple cookies values

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I noticed somthing about multiple cookies in asp.net
  that when you add new values in different postbacks the earlier values will deleted and the last values only will be stay

-For example (VB.net)
  in Default1.aspx.vb

```
Response.Cookies("mycookie")("abc") = 123
```

in Default2.aspx.vb

```
Response.Cookies("mycookie")("def") = 456
```

now if default1 executed the "abc" value will stored in "mycookie" but if then defualt2 executed the "abc" value will replaced with the new "def" value !.

I tried the following solution, but I am not comfortable with it because I think it take a lot of resources without meaning:
  in Default2.aspx.vb

```
Dim OldValues As NameValueCollection = Request.Cookies.Get("mycookie").Values
Response.Cookies.Get("mycookie").Values.Clear()
Response.Cookies.Get("mycookie").Values.Add(OldValues)
Response.Cookies.Get("mycookie").Values.Add("def", 456)
```

Now, Is there any other option to do this, like disable somthing in settings or anything to prevent overwrite earlier values ?

thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

hmmm, no ideas ?!

anyway, since there no other options, I decide to use my code and do some capsulation, and for public benfit I will posting my codes here may benefit some interested brothers.

the main idea here that I develop a big web application and I need to store users choices in multi levels scope, for example saving order by preferences, No of items per page, etc.. and in multi level scopes such as saving preferences in long time period (in cookies) or in short time period (in session).

and because these choeses is too many I forced to use multiple cookies because a small limitation number of cookies allowed in some browsers.

here is capsulated functions to do this trick:

```
Public Enum StoredPropertyScope As SByte
    SessionAndCookies = 0
    SessionOnly = 1
    CookiesOnly = 2
End Enum
Public Shared Function GetStoredProperty(ByVal group As String, ByVal Key As String, Optional scope As StoredPropertyScope = StoredPropertyScope.SessionAndCookies) As Object
    If (scope = StoredPropertyScope.SessionAndCookies Or scope = StoredPropertyScope.SessionOnly) And Not (HttpContext.Current.Session(group & "-" & Key) Is Nothing) Then
        Return HttpContext.Current.Session(group & "-" & Key)
    Else
        If (scope = StoredPropertyScope.SessionAndCookies Or scope = StoredPropertyScope.CookiesOnly) And Not (Request.Cookies(group) Is Nothing) Then
            Return Request.Cookies(group)(Key)
        Else
            Return Nothing
        End If
    End If
End Function
Public Shared Sub SetStoredProperty(ByVal group As String, ByVal key As String, value As String, Optional scope As StoredPropertyScope = StoredPropertyScope.SessionAndCookies)
    If scope = StoredPropertyScope.SessionAndCookies Or scope = StoredPropertyScope.CookiesOnly Then
        If Request.Cookies(group) Is Nothing Then
            Response.Cookies(group)(key) = value
            Response.Cookies(group).Expires = Now.AddYears(1)
        Else
            Dim OldValues As NameValueCollection = Request.Cookies.Get(group).Values
            OldValues.Item(key) = value
            Response.Cookies.Get(group).Values.Clear()
            Response.Cookies.Get(group).Values.Add(OldValues)
            Response.Cookies(group).Expires = Now.AddYears(1)
        End If
    End If
    If scope = StoredPropertyScope.SessionAndCookies Or scope = StoredPropertyScope.SessionOnly Then
        HttpContext.Current.Session(group & "-" & key) = value
    End If
End Sub
Public Overloads Shared Sub RemoveStoredProperty(ByVal group As String, ByVal key As String, Optional scope As StoredPropertyScope = StoredPropertyScope.SessionAndCookies)
    If scope = StoredPropertyScope.SessionAndCookies Or scope = StoredPropertyScope.CookiesOnly Then
        If Not (Request.Cookies(group) Is Nothing) AndAlso Request.Cookies(group).HasKeys Then
            Dim OldValues As NameValueCollection = Request.Cookies.Get(group).Values
            OldValues.Remove(key)
            Response.Cookies.Get(group).Values.Clear()
            Response.Cookies.Get(group).Values.Add(OldValues)
            Response.Cookies(group).Expires = Now.AddYears(1)
        End If
    End If
    If scope = StoredPropertyScope.SessionAndCookies Or scope = StoredPropertyScope.SessionOnly Then
        HttpContext.Current.Session.Remove(group & "-" & key)
    End If
End Sub
Public Overloads Shared Sub RemoveStoredProperty(ByVal group As String)
    'remove all from cookies only
    Response.Cookies(group).Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)
End Sub
Public Shared Function CheckStoredProperty(ByVal group As String, ByVal key As String) As StoredPropertyScope
    'return where is property stored or -1 if not exists
    Dim result As StoredPropertyScope = -1
    If (Not Request.Cookies(group) Is Nothing) AndAlso (Not Request.Cookies(group)(key) Is Nothing) Then
        result = StoredPropertyScope.CookiesOnly
    End If
    If Not HttpContext.Current.Session(group & "-" & key) Is Nothing Then
        If result = -1 Then result = StoredPropertyScope.SessionOnly Else result = StoredPropertyScope.SessionAndCookies
    End If
    Return result
End Function
```

HOW TO USE
 1- first you need to decument all names of properties group and sub keys, because you will use it as string values so its your responsibility to make sure its right.

2- to store value use code like this:

```
SetStoredProperty("userSelections", "itemsOrderedBy", "Price", StoredPropertyScope.SessionAndCookies)
```

- the first parameter is the group name and it will be the cookie name, and the second parameter is the proberty name (sub value in cookie), and the second parameter is the value of the problerty, and the fourth parameter is optional to determine where you want to store this value (session only or cookies only or both).

*Note (cookie expire date is 1 year and you can change it directly from code)

3- to retrieve value :

```
GetStoredProperty("userSelections", "itemsOrderdBy",  StoredPropertyScope.CookiesOnly)
```

- the third parameter is optional and if you choice SessionAndCookies the priority of returned value will be to session

4- to remove value:

```
RemoveStoredProperty("userSelections")  
RemoveStoredProperty("userSelections", "itemsOrderdBy", StoredPropertyScope.SessionAndCookies)
```

- the first line will delete entire group (cookie) and it use for cookies only. and the second line will remove specified property from the scope determined in the optional third parameter

5- Where the property stored:

```
 CheckStoredProperty("userSelections", "itemsOrderdBy")
```

- this function will search for proberty and if it exists will return where is it (StoredPropertyScope enum) and if not exists at all will return -1

I hope that will be useful, and if there any better solution please let me know.
Thanks